# How do you add background music in Swift

Tags: swift

I want to know how to add background music in Swift for a project Im working on

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow ! Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `AVAudioPlayer`:

```
let soundFilePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("mySound", ofType: "mySound")
let soundFileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: soundFilePath!)
let player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: soundFileURL, error: nil)
player.numberOfLoops = -1 //infinite
player.play()
```

And don't forget to `import AVFoundation` in your Project.